# Is there a built-in perl function that determines length of numeric variable?

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing a text file with the following format that needs to be distinguished.

```
cat       dog      [numeric, 00-23]
pickle    fence    [numeric, 0-5]
tack      glue     [numeric,1-53]
dent      paint    [numeric01-15]
```

If the minimum of the range is a single digit, then I need to process it a certain way. If the minimum of the range is double-digit (including 00,01,02,etc), I need to process it another way.

```
if($line =~ /\[numeric.*(\d+)\-(\d+)/i){
       $rangemin=$1;
       $rangemax=$2;
       #find # of digits in $rangemin
       #length() doesn't work
       #I'm trying to find a function that finds number of digits so length of `00` or `01` or `02` or etc. returns `2` 
}
```

How do I find the # of digits of `$rangemin`?

Comment: What about `length`? Why do you say it does not work?

Comment: `length(00)` returns `1` for me. I'm trying to find a stretch of digits so length of `00` or `01` or `02` or etc. returns `2`

Comment: `length(00)` returns 1 because it is the same as `length(0)`, or `length('0')`. `length('00')` returns 2.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, `length(00)` does return `1`, but that's not the cause of your problem. This isn't a string-vs-number issue, you're just passing the wrong string, as explained in the accepted answer. (I'm adding this comment for the benefit of future readers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regular expression grabs the leading 0 because `.*` is very greedy.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /\[numeric[\D]*(\d+)\-(\d+)/i){
        my $rangemin = $1;
        my $len = length $rangemin;
        print "rangemin=$rangemin len=$len\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
cat       dog      [numeric, 00-23]
pickle    fence    [numeric, 0-5]
tack      glue     [numeric,1-53]
dent      paint    [numeric01-15]
```

Output:

```
rangemin=00 len=2
rangemin=0 len=1
rangemin=1 len=1
rangemin=01 len=2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) built-in, just like you would for a string; Perl implicitly converts arguments based on the operator/builtin that they are being passed to:

```
#!perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $number = 5; 
print length($number), "\n";
```

You can also use a base-10 logarithm to determine how long a number is:

```
#!perl 

use strict;
use warnings; 

my $number = 12345;
my $length = $number > 0 
    ? int(log($number)/log(10)) + 1
    : $number == 0 
          ? 0 
          : int(log(abs($number))/log(10)) + 2;
print $length, "\n"; 
# 5
```

**EDIT: as @Keith Thompson points out, log is not defined for numbers <= 0. Use [abs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/abs.html) to prevent this condition.

Comment: I would like to find a stretch of digits so that the length of `05` returns `2`

Comment: The `log` method fails for non-positive numbers.

Comment: Just using `abs` would (a) blow up on `log(0)` and (b) would report that the length of `-42` is 2 rather than 3.

Comment: And it wouldn't fix the problem. See the accepted answer.

Comment: It answers the question that was initially asked, "How do I find the length of a number?". New information changed the question after I wrote this.